# Android заливка файлов на сервер, socket таймаут

Tags: android, сокет, android-asynctask

В 90% случаев я получаю:

```
02-14 14:51:35.513 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: [socket][3:-1] exception
02-14 14:51:35.514 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: close [socket][::/:::-1]
02-14 14:51:35.515 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
02-14 14:51:35.515 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:341)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:221)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:197)
02-14 14:51:35.516 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:392)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:356)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:273)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:474)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.example.android.camera2basic.FilesUploadingTask.doInBackground(FilesUploadingTask.java:86)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at com.example.android.camera2basic.FilesUploadingTask.doInBackground(FilesUploadingTask.java:27)
02-14 14:51:35.517 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
02-14 14:51:35.518 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-14 14:51:35.518 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
02-14 14:51:35.518 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
02-14 14:51:35.518 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
02-14 14:51:35.518 9599-12100/com.example.android.camera2basic W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Но иногда раздупляется и работает нормально, а потом внезапно опять таймауты, wifi стабильный, с сетью все в порядке 100%.

Вот мой код для заливки на сервер:

```
package com.example.android.camera2basic;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Загружает файл на сервер
 */

public class FilesUploadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    // Конец строки
    private String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    // Два тире
    private String twoHyphens = "--";
    // Разделитель
    private String boundary =  "----WebKitFormBoundary9xFB2hiUhzqbBQ4M";

    // Переменные для считывания файла в оперативную память
    private int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    // Путь к файлу в памяти устройства
    private String filePath;


    // Адрес метода api для загрузки файла на сервер
    public static final String API_FILES_UPLOADING_PATH = "http://xxxxxxx.com/send.php";

    // Ключ, под которым файл передается на сервер
    public static final String FORM_FILE_NAME = "photo";

    public FilesUploadingTask(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


        // Результат выполнения запроса, полученный от сервера
        String result = null;

        try {

            // Создание ссылки для отправки файла
            URL uploadUrl = new URL(API_FILES_UPLOADING_PATH);
            Log.i("up", "uploading " + filePath);
            // Создание соединения для отправки файла
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uploadUrl.openConnection();

            // Разрешение ввода соединению
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            // Разрешение вывода соединению
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            // Отключение кеширования
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Задание запросу типа POST
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // Задание необходимых свойств запросу
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

            // Создание потока для записи в соединение
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            // Формирование multipart контента

            // Начало контента
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            // Заголовок элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                    FORM_FILE_NAME + "\"; filename=\"" + filePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    //filePath + "\"; filename=\"" + filePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
            // Тип данных элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
            // Конец заголовка
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // Поток для считывания файла в оперативную память
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Считывание файла в оперативную память и запись его в соединение
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // Конец элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Получение ответа от сервера
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("up", "upload reponse " + serverResponseCode);
            // Закрытие соединений и потоков
            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            // Считка ответа от сервера в зависимости от успеха
            if(serverResponseCode == 200) {
                result = readStream(connection.getInputStream());
            } else {
                result = readStream(connection.getErrorStream());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Считка потока в строку
    public static String readStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы говорите что 100% сеть есть, думаю причины основные это:

1) Значение connect Timeout стоит очень маленький, вам нужно поиграться с параметрам setConnectTimeout(int timeout) к примеру установить 60 секунд (зависит от ваших бизнес требований).

2) Возможно вас сервер переодически блокирует входящие соединения от клиентов (нужно мониторить и дебажить).